# Battery life in Samsung Galaxy 3

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging, samsung-galaxy-apollo

I recently updated my Samsung Galaxy 3 to Android 2.2 . After the update my fully charged battery dies in just 3 hours(without any use) and around 1 hour if I use it (talking,browsing etc). I am using the phone for the past one year. This is too annoying because I am not able to use it anywhere outside. The battery quickly dies.

When I used Android 2.1 , the battery used to come for 1 full day

Is this battery problem because of the updated from 2.1 to 2.2 ?

Are there any work arounds for this ?

Comment: Any abnormalities shows in battery usage?

Comment: No. Nothing abnormal as such. I mean what is "abnormal"?

Comment: Shows any program eating too much battery? Or why don't you install watchdog and see if any program is eating too much CPU.

Comment: Did your display brightness settings get reset after installing the upgrade?  (Or other battery-saving settings that you used to have set that might've gotten reset, like WiFi scanning?)

Comment: I switch of wifi when I am not in home, keep the display to minimum. My doubt is , did the battery degrage after using it for 1 year or something ?

Comment: Sounds like it's not sleeping properly, though it could be related to battery stats or battery wear.  Are you rooted?  If so I would try clearing the battery stats.

Comment: Where your phone fully charged when you updated its firmware?

Comment: If not yet solved: You might want to check [Battery life cut in half recently - DrReadUsbStatus issue?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27436/battery-life-cut-in-half-recently-drreadusbstatus-issue/27445#27445), which should give you a few hints on how to figure out the responsible process (if any).

Comment: You also might want to check [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/how-to-deal-with-orphaned-wakelocks) -- could be an app misbehaving. // If your problem was already solved in the meantime (as you are not responding to any comments), it would be nice if you add an answer and letting us know the solution.